# System and out in java

Tags: java

I am new java user. Recently I have learned that `out` (Which we use at `System.out.println`) is a java standard output object.

My question is; I never created this object by myself or haven't found any code  which creates this object. So how it is accessible to use?

And more over I think `System` is a class name. If so, is `out` a static member of the `System` class, since we are accessing `out` without creating a new object of `System` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, System is a class and out is a static member variable of that class.

```
public final class System {
    public static final PrintStream out = ...;
    public static final PrintStream err = ...;
    public static final InputStream in = ...;
    ...
}
```

See the [Java documentation for System class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Answer (score 3):

yep, this lives on the System object:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

A good way to learn a language (and to have the right answers) is to look at the API source.
in `System.java`

```
...
public final static PrintStream out = null;
...
```

you don't need to create object in order to access static members